# Using CSS3 hover effect, how can I move the text left 5 pixels and move it back?

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

Let's say I have an anchor tag.  When the anchor tag is hovered besides just the color and background color changing, how can I use transitions to move the text in the anchor tag to move 5 pixels to right when it's hovered and a second or so later it should go back to the original position.

Comment: Should it go back even if the person is still hovering over it?

Comment: @kalley yes, i forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a little javascript, everything is smooth (the css below is the bare necessities):

```css
a {
    display: inline-block; /* this just has to be block-level */
    -webkit-animation: moveAndBack 1s ease-in-out;
}
a.not-ready {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0;
}
a:hover {
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveAndBack {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(0); }
    25% { -webkit-transform: translateX(5px); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(5px); }
}
```

### [See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/R2RAt/4/)

And the only thing the javascript is doing is stopping the animation from running on load.

Latest edit and update to fiddle takes care of an issue that would only happen if you hovered on the link long enough for the animation to complete. It wouldn't restart the next time. So, javascript clones and replaces the link on `mouseout`.

Answer (score 4):

A solution using css animations and `text-indent` ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6WNS/2/)):

```
a {
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: INDENT 2s 1; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    INDENT 2s 1; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      INDENT 2s 1; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         INDENT 2s 1; /* IE 10+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes INDENT{  
  0%   { text-indent: 0; }
  50% { text-indent: 5px; }
  100% { text-indent: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes INDENT {
  0%   { text-indent: 0; }
  50% { text-indent: 5px; }
  100% { text-indent: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes INDENT {
  0%   { text-indent: 0; }
  50% { text-indent: 5px; }
  100% { text-indent: 0; }
}
@keyframes INDENT {
  0%   { text-indent: 0; }
  50% { text-indent: 5px; }
  100% { text-indent: 0; }
}
```

You may have to change the settings a little bit to get a smoother animation. You can achieve a delay by tuning the keyframes. To get a delay of 1 second in an animation of 2 seconds it would be something like that ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6WNS/3/)):

```
@keyframes INDENT{  
  0%   { text-indent: 0; }
  25% { text-indent: 5px; }
  75% { text-indent: 5px; }
  100% { text-indent: 0; }
}
```

You can [check browser support of css animations on caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-animation).

Comment: it jolts back while I know that it's possible to do this with the back animation in css only